# how to automount an external HDD to nautilus?

Tags: boot, mount, external-hdd, automount, fdisk

After using `unetbootin` to install an `iso` image to a [portable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073B4YHLV) hdd [disk enclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_enclosure) I cannot view or mount the drive through nautilus.

How can I make the drive viewable in nautilus?   It does show in `fdisk` as `sdb1`:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3b9b7b5e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 156301311 156299264 74.5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 55.9 GiB, 60011642880 bytes, 117210240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe833c75e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 117210239 117208192 55.9G 83 Linux
thufir@doge:~$
```

there's nothing of value on the disk.  Previously it would just show in nautilus.  Running nautilus with `sudo` shows:

[image: nautilus]

not sure whether that's the external hdd or not.  The `tail` command shows:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Aug 17 20:51:23 doge compiz[1919]: console.error:
Aug 17 20:51:23 doge compiz[1919]:   Message: TypeError: can't access dead object
Aug 17 20:51:23 doge compiz[1919]:   Stack:
Aug 17 20:51:23 doge compiz[1919]:     load_into_window@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-qofqdk4qzufgwq-at-jetpack/lib/process-script.js:82:1
Aug 17 20:51:23 doge compiz[1919]: load_into_window/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-qofqdk4qzufgwq-at-jetpack/lib/process-script.js:107:28
Aug 17 20:51:23 doge compiz[1919]: notify@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/timers.js:40:9
Aug 17 20:51:54 doge evolution-sourc[1733]: secret_service_search_sync: must specify at least one attribute to match
Aug 17 20:54:31 doge kernel: [ 3978.343635] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
Aug 17 20:54:44 doge gnome-terminal-[2145]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x55f9dac41cc0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Aug 17 20:54:53 doge sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/thufir is already mounted
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.412231] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.561533] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1040
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.561538] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.561542] usb 2-4: Product: MHT2060AT       
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.561545] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Initio
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.561548] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 0000000000000000W
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.562007] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge kernel: [ 4025.562545] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4"
Aug 17 20:55:18 doge mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.593256] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Initio   MHT2060AT        1.06 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.594950] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.595731] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 117210240 512-byte logical blocks: (60.0 GB/55.9 GiB)
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.596800] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.596806] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.597906] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.597917] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.611118]  sdb: sdb1
Aug 17 20:55:19 doge kernel: [ 4026.616302] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

not able to explicitly mount:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ dmesg | tail
[38425.298930]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad
[38425.298932] RIP: 0033:0x7f32d242e987
[38425.298934] RSP: 002b:00007fffd3152ed8 EFLAGS: 00003246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[38425.298936] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055ce5c648670 RCX: 00007f32d242e987
[38425.298938] RDX: 00007fffd3152f10 RSI: 00000000c05064a7 RDI: 000000000000000e
[38425.298939] RBP: 00007fffd3152f10 R08: 000055ce5c648720 R09: 0000000000000000
[38425.298941] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000003246 R12: 00000000c05064a7
[38425.298942] R13: 000000000000000e R14: 00007fffd3152f10 R15: 000000000000000e
[38425.298944] ---[ end trace 71aae897cab69e2e ]---
[38737.380862] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
thufir@doge:~$
```

although it *does* show with `fdisk -l`...

Comment: Try to mount manually. Maybe you get a useful output: `mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /mnt` ([via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72125/236063))

Comment: @RoVo no luck, but thanks for the link.  question updated with output.  I think it's formatted oddly, or not formatted, or something.  can you mount something that's not formatted?  seems like a chicken-or-the-egg problem..

Comment: see http://paste.ubuntu.com/25353265/   -- trying to format with parted.  Not sure whether it worked or not...